# Image on Qt QMdiArea background

Tags: image, qt, qt4, qmdiarea

Qt developers!
Is there are way to add image on the background of my midArea like on picture below?

[image]

I know I can use something like this

```
QImage img("logo.jpg");
mdiArea->setBackground(img);
```

But I don't need any repeat of my image on the background.

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you could try to override the `QMdiArea::paintEvent()` and draw your logo pixmap there?

Comment: @vahancho oh, well, could you show some example with it, please?

Comment: Sure, please find the working example in my posted answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I said in my comment above, you can sub-class the `QMdiArea`, override its `paintEvent()` function and draw your logo image yourself (in the bottom right corner). Here is the sample code that implements the mentioned idea:

```
class MdiArea : public QMdiArea
{
public:
    MdiArea(QWidget *parent = 0)
        :
            QMdiArea(parent),
            m_pixmap("logo.jpg")
    {}
protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
    {
        QMdiArea::paintEvent(event);

        QPainter painter(viewport());

        // Calculate the logo position - the bottom right corner of the mdi area.
        int x = width() - m_pixmap.width();
        int y = height() - m_pixmap.height();
        painter.drawPixmap(x, y, m_pixmap);
    }
private:
    // Store the logo image.
    QPixmap m_pixmap;
};
```

And finally use the custom mdi area in the main window:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QMainWindow mainWindow;
    QMdiArea *mdiArea = new MdiArea(&mainWindow);
    mainWindow.setCentralWidget(mdiArea);
    mainWindow.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Oh, great, thank you! And is there way without editing original qt module code? Because I got free version, and as far as I know I am not suppose to edit such things

Comment: @DanilGholtsman, actually there is no change in Qt source code. The sample code I posted is supposed to be your own code, and you can do this without any restriction.

Comment: oh, I see! there is extending! first time I saw it i was a distracted little bit, sorry for really stupid question ._.